# Почему Xcode не видит Swift класса в скомпилированном фреймверке?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Есть задача - сделать несколько Swift классов в виде скомпилированного фреймверка.

На гитхабе есть проект показываюсь как создать фреймверк содержащий swift класс - https://github.com/crspybits/CocoaTouchFramework .

В примере этого проекта подключения фреймверка идет через импортирование xcode проекта.

Я создал новый swift проект и добавил туда уже скомпилированный SimpleFramework.framework из выше упомянутого репозитория и получил ошибку:

*ViewController.swift:12:22: 'SimpleClass' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class*

То есть xcode не видет класса SimpleClass. Что не так?

```
 //
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import SimpleFramework

@objc class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var object = SimpleClass("fwe")

    }

}
```

Мой тестовый проект на github: https://github.com/nullproduction/TestApp

Comment: а есть где то посмотреть ваш simpleFramework? не компилированный

Comment: https://github.com/crspybits/CocoaTouchFramework/tree/master/swift-framework-example/SimpleFramework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вкратце, ситуация такая: когда вы собираете framework он учитывает не все возможные архитектуры. Другими словами, если при сборке указано устройство, сборка будет только под устройство, если симулятор — то только под симулятор.

Соответственно, когда вы импортируете framework в приложение, то и приложение наследует ту же зависимость - если к нему подключен framework собранный для устройства, то и приложение будет работать только на устройстве. Например ваш пример из github отлично работает на устройстве, но выдает ошибку при компиляции на симулятор.

Что с этим делать?

В набор command line инструментов xcode входит инструмент под названием 'lipo', который соединяет библиотеки собранные для разных платформ в одну. Вам надо скомпилировать свой фреймворк отдельно под устройство и отдельно под симулятор, и потом при помощи lipo объединить в один. Вот [неплохой пример](https://gist.github.com/cromandini/1a9c4aeab27ca84f5d79) того, как это может выглядеть. Если надо больше информации, ищите по словам: `universal framework`